# Angular error handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I have this code for a token, generated with JWT and returning it to the application if the user is successfully logged.

```
var token = $localStorage.token;
var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
var tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
```

then I validate if the token have the `webUserId` claim

```
if(tokenObj.webUserId){...}
```

If I replace the value of localstorage tokeb I expect an error because is not a good one, but when the code cames to this point:

var tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(base64));

It sends me an Angular `$exceptionHandler`. How can I controlle this error in my code to avoid an angular exception?

Comment: Either use exception handling with standard try-catch, or just prevalidate/null-check your stuff before doing stuff.

Comment: @ryanyuyu but the error is not because its null, its because it cannot apply `atob(base64)`, so I'll try with a try-catch.